# AngularJS: request fails when withCredentials : true (request canceled)

Tags: ajax, angularjs, http

I have this problem with AngularJS $http request:

This works:

```
$http({url : endpoint, withCredentials: false}); // success
```

This doesn't:

```
$http({url : endpoint, withCredentials: true}); // error
```

Server configuration:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
```

When I look into the Google Chrome console I see Status: (canceled) and warning: "provisional headers are shown". What's interesting, in Opera request status is OK and I can see the response.

I've been looking for an answer and found nothing. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that it was about Access-Control-Allow-Origin wildcard. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true.
Setting it to:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://the.domain.it.was.called.from");
```

solved the problem.